# Eclipse Oxygen in ubuntu Can't Acess Network shares

Tags: php, eclipse, ubuntu, developer-tools

I Have Eclipse Oxygen running in my Ubuntu 16.04. I Tried to access my network share from the eclipse. my development environment is in samba shared network from one of my Ubuntu rack server. Please provide me idea to get rid from this